# How do I create a javascript classes

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is create a object that will handle my ajax calls, I need to repeatedly refresh a few pages over and over again, and create a object for each page is the only way I can think of to do that, and still have the ajax code asynchronous. But whenever I test this nothing is happening and I don't know why.

Here is my code

```
function PageLoader(url,id,repeatTime){
    this.id = id;
    this.url = url; 
    this.repeatTime = repeatTime;

    this.start = function(){        
        var time = Date.now();
        var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xml.open("GET",this.url,true);
        xml.onreadystatechange = function(){        
            if(xml.readyState === 4){
                document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML = xml.responseText+" <small>("+(Date.now()-time)+")</small>";

                if(this.repeatTime > 0){
                    setTimeout(this.start,this.repeatTime);
                }
            }
        }

        xml.send(null);
    }

    this.stop = function(){
        this.repeatTime = -1;
    }
}
```

And here is how I try to run it.

```
var infoAjax = new PageLoader('../modules/userinfo.php','StatusInfo',1000);

//Load everything automaticly
window.onload = function(){
    infoAjax.start();
}
```

Comment: See [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback). It would be better if you explained your problem properly, then we can provide better help. If you just want to know how to do OOP in JavaScript, have a look at the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: I'm failing to understand exactly what the problem here is. Throw a "new" in front of this and voila - new object.

Comment: "not working" is not useful. what is the exact progblem? (BTW, JavaScript has no classes, it uses prototypal inheritance.)

Comment: it looks right... what are you trying to use to create the object?

Comment: The problem is that the responseText never shows up on the element, and even if I use an alert to new it, the timeout never happens since I only get one alert call.

Comment: Have a look at the question I linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback. With a bit of debugging you will find out that `this` doesn't refer to what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks so much, I changed all `this` into `self` which is simply `var self = this` and it works perfectly now ^^

Comment: The following answer could be of use to you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll get to the networking, but I'd like to take a minute to explain a few things about JavaScript.

First off, JavaScript has no notion of classes in the traditional sense. Every object in JavaScript has a prototype that allows that object to access foreign properties as though they were properties of that object. For example, `var point = {x: 0, y: 10}` creates a variable `point` referencing an object with two local keys `x` and `y`, but `point` also has prototype properties that can be accessed (e.g., `point.hasOwnProperty` is a function from `Object.prototype` — which is common to most JavaScript objects). The `this` keyword is were things gets interesting. Whenever a function is called, the `this` keyword refers to the object that "owns" that function. If I did something like `point.incrementX = function () { this.x++; }` the `this` would refer to `point` because it "owns" the `incrementX` function. JavaScript allows you to override this ownership by calling `.call` on a function an supplying a an object to use as `this` inside the body of the function. Constructors are where JavaScript really confuses things. When the `new` keyword is applied to a function it does two things. First it constructs an object whose prototype is set to the `prototype` property of the constructor function. Then it supplies that object to the constructor as `this`. So really when you do `var obj = new Constructor()` its like doing `var obj = Object.create(Constructor.prototype); Constructor.call(obj)` (`Object.create` creates an object whose prototype is set to the supplied object).

Anyhow, back to the point. Instead of creating methods for your `PageLoader` object inside the constructor, consider putting them in the `prototype` property of `PageLoader`.

```
PageLoader.prototype = {
   start: function () { ... },
   stop: function () { ... }
};

// or

PageLoader.prototype.start = function () { ... };
PageLoader.prototype.stop = function () { ... };
```

The other thing — likely the reason your code isn't working — is the use of `this` inside the `onreadystatechange` event callback. When you used `this` it was actually referring to the `xml` variable instead of the `PageLoader` instance. To fix this simply put a variable declaration such as `var self = this;` above the `xml.onreadystatechange` callback.

-- EDIT --

Admittedly my explanation `this` was a bit weak. If you'de like a more description explanation please checkout the MDN page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: *"If I did something like `point.incrementX = function () { this.x++; }` the `this` would refer to point because it "owns" the `incrementX` function."* That is not very precise. The definition  doesn't determine at all which value `this` refers to. It's only determined by *how* the function is called (unless you `.bind()` it). So in your short example, you can't make any statement about the value of `this`. It will on;y refer to `point` if it's called with `point.incrementX()`. If you do `var foo = point.incrementX; foo();`, then `this` will refer to `window`.

Comment: @FelixKling I understand, I was trying to keep things simple. I'll update my answer.